# in chrome, word-wrap: break-word breaks words even if there is no space

Tags: css, google-chrome

The following markup and CSS causes weird behaviour in Chrome:

```css
#parent {
  background: yellow;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#box {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OIL</div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OWL</div>
</div>
```

> **Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7sq3ybxr/

The upper example (containing the word OIL), causes word breaks even though there is literally no room to the right. The lower one doesn't. I'm assuming it's got something to do with the character width. In other browsers, the word is always displayed below the box, as expected.

Does anybody know what causes this behaviour or have an idea for a workaround? The size, float and word-wrap properties must stay, however.

**Edit:** Oh, by the way, writing the markup like this seems to fix it, but it's not something I have control over (imagine user input via tinyMCE):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div>
        OIL
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This appears to be a bug in Chrome.

### In Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m the expected result was displayed

[image]

### In Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m the undesired result is displayed

[image]

## What can be done to avoid this issue?

I imagine that this bug will be fixed in time, but in the meantime you could use `letter-spacing` to increase the amount of space taken by the letters and force the expected behaviour.

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.box {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.word {
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="word">OIL</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="word">OWL</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gzunowg/)

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative! I neglected to mention that the text style is user-determined, but letter-spacing might just be subtle enough to work around the issue and be minimally invasive. For lack of anything that actually fixes this, I'll mark your solution accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements in css causes errors like this. In previous versions of Internet explorer, we used to see problems like this all the time.

If I float one element, and want others stay intact, I usually use "clear:both" on the next element so that that element and the elements after that would not be effected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as my post states, the floating behaviour needs to stay, even though the element is 100% wide. The reason is that this element is actually resizable via drag & drop.

Comment: You wont lost the floating behavior. It will only effect the element you dont want floating at.

Comment: Then I don't think I understand. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: When you use "clear" property, No floating elements allowed on the left or the right side of a specified element. 
So you can continue to float the red box in given example but not the div element that contains text inside. give the clear property to the text containing div.

Comment: Ok I get it, your container width is responsive, hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Give a space character after the OIL or any unbreakable word. This might fix the error. Since word-wrap is breaking all the alphabets in the word.

```css
#parent {
  background: yellow;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#box {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OIL </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OWL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but as my edit states, this is something I don't have control over, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
      background: yellow;
      height: 120px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      width: 100px;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      
    }
    #box {
      background: red;
      height: 100px;
      float:left;
      width: 100%;
    }
.box-2 {
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
      <div id="box"></div>
      <div class="box-2">OIL</div>
    </div>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="box"></div>
        <div>
            OIL
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As my post states, the floating behaviour needs to stay. The reason is that the floating element is resizable via drag & drop, so the box isn't necessarily always 100% wide, which is when the break-word property needs to do its thing.

Comment: As I said before, adding whitespaces to the word is not an option because it is not something I have control over.

Comment: I've use <code>clear:both</code> on Yellow Part, What is wrong with it?

Comment: The problem with that is that the text is no longer floating around the box. The box can become less than 100% wide, in which case the text should be displayed to its right.

Comment: You can also use display:inline-block on the place of float:left; If require

Comment: If I do that, the text also doesn't float around the box if the box is smaller than 100%. And I also neglected to mention that the #box div can also float to the right in other cases. Thanks for your input, though!

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements are out-of-flow, so they overlap following blocks, unless they establish a block formatting context. That shouldn't be a problem, because line boxes are reduced, so the text should be pushed below the float in a full-width line box.

However, for some reason, this layout confuses Chrome. To fix this, you can establish a block formatting context with `display: inline-block`.

```css
#parent {
  background: yellow;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#box {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#box + div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OIL</div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>OWL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but if I do that, the text won't flow around the box at all if it happens to be smaller than 100% of its parent width.